# C++ and sqlite3, connection only opens once after compilation

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am creating a wrapper class for working with sqlite3 in a command-line C++ application on my macbook. The database connection only works once after compilation.

First, the wrapper class (`cmodel::dbpath` is defined in another header, and I output it in the constructor to be sure):

```
class dbconnect {
    sqlite3    *db;
    const char *dbname;
public:
    dbconnect();
    ~dbconnect();
};

dbconnect::dbconnect() :
    dbname(cmodel::dbpath) {

    // Output the path
    std::cout << this->dbname << std::endl;

    sqlite3_initialize();

    // initialize this->db
    int state = sqlite3_open_v2(this->dbname, &(this->db), SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);

    if(state == SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("Database opened successfully\n");       
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(this->db));
    }
}

dbconnect::~dbconnect() {
    std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
    sqlite3_close_v2(this->db);
    sqlite3_shutdown();
}
```

The `main()` function

```
int main() {
    dbconnect db;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my prompt

```
$ make
g++ -lpthread -ldl ... /Users/awesomeuser/bin/cmodel
$ cmodel # first run
/Users/awesomeuser/.cmodel/cmodel.db
Database opened successfully
Destructor called
$ cmodel # second run
/Users/awesomeuser/.cmodel/cmodel.db
unable to open database file
Destructor called
```

To be honest, I'm not a big fan of these specific questions, but I'm just baffled. Any idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**

Ok here's something extra which is happening. When I open the db in the mode `SQLITE_READWRITE | SQLITE_CREATE` (which creates the database if it doesn't exist), a new database is created titled `cmodel.XTUM` in the same directory as `cmodel.db`. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: After the 1st run, can you verify that `/Users/awesomeuser/.cmodel/cmodel.db` actually exists?

Comment: 1. SQLITE3 creates a journal file in the same directory as of the db path. Can you check the status for each run (permission, size etc).  2. Can run program with strace command, It will help in understanding the issue with DB (in case we have one).

Comment: First, thank you both for replying. I just did the same compile-and-run, and the result of `ls -la ~/.cmodel` is `-rwxr-xr-x   1 awesomeuser  staff  14336  9 Feb 13:50 cmodel.db`. So it's still there. @kumar_m_kiran, I can't see the journal entry; also I'm not familiar with `strace`, can you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to trace syscalls invoked within `/bin/ls`, you have only to run `strace /bin/ls`.  By the way, SQLite should be shipped with a command line client.  Can you try `sqlite3 ~/.cmodel/cmodel.db` and then `.tables` ?

Comment: To answer your question @nodakai, the database opens normally when I open it with the shell. All the tables display, no problem. I did a quick search online, and it seems that Mac OS X has an `strace` equivalent called `dtruss`. I'll post something in an update in a second, but take a look at the first update and tell me if you see anything familiar (if you have the chance).

Comment: `cmodel.XTUM` must be "2.4 Master Journal Files" https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html